# What does the number in parenthesis really mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I always thought that the number in the parenthesis represented the *field length*?

However, I understand that is not always the case. Maybe it's a MySQL issue? Someone told me if I set a field to 9 characters long, I can add a value that's more than 9 characters but only the first 9 will be saved.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    id INT,
    age INT(2)
);
```

If that's the case, shouldn't I select something like `TINYINT` instead of `INT` for age?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`INT(2)` will generate an INT with the [minimum display width of 2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html):

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.

this does **not** affect the range of possible values that can be stored in the field; neither is it the number of bytes used to store it. It seems to be only a recommendation for applications how to show the value, unless `ZEROFILL` is used (see the linked page).

A unsigned `TINYINT` (0...255) would probably do as well, unless [cryopreservation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryopreservation) takes a big step forward during the lifetime of your application.

Comment: And it continues: "The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly."

Comment: so why bother implying that the field can take a value of up to 2? I don't think that has anything to do w/ the length of the value for mysql's internal, correct? It's just a display thing.

Comment: @Anders, is that a mysql issue or does it apply to postgres, oracle and others?

Comment: @lucky it's only a display thing, and what's more, it seems to be nothing more than a recommendation for applications. The exception is if you use `ZEROFILL` in which case the value will be padded: `1` => `01`...

Comment: @Anders I added the 2nd paragraph for clarity

Comment: for vchar, `name(10)` means display up to 10 chars, I can fit more than 10 chars i assume?

Comment: @luckytaxi no, for `varchar`, it is the actual maximum width that a value can take.

Comment: nice, all this time ive been using INT. tinyint would've suffice for many of my fields. thx for the clarification.

Comment: @Pekka Your link has rotted. The page is still there, but no longer contains any of the words "minimum", "display" or "width". It looks like they've moved it to the [Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html) page. I would have proposed an edit, but I'm not sure what to do with the original text you have quoted. It seems worth keeping to me.

Comment: I still don't understand. int(11) is an integer value, what have it to do with padding? I thought padding is for character type. The official doc said "int(4) zerofill" will return a vlaue of 5 as '0005'. But int is integer value, how can it has padding 0?

Comment: @ScottChu it's stored internally as an integer value, but is output with the leading zeroes.

Comment: [new link to article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

Answer (score -4):

That's the case for field types like vchar, but for numbers it represents the number of bytes which it uses to represent the number.  An integer of two bytes means you can hold a number 2^16 - 1 (8 bits in a byte, so 16 total).  If it's age, I figure you ought to be safe with two bytes.  ;)

Comment: I used to think the `(2)` stood for bytes too, but it's incorrect.

Comment: ah ok, so it's more for vchar. So if I wanted to display SSN, I shouldn't have do `ssn INT(9)`

Comment: Apparently I was mistaken.  Listen to Pekka.  o.O