# mySQL datatypes - why is there a number after int: int(11)

Tags: mysql, types

According to the [mySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) a datatype of int (signed) has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. When I create a table with phpMyAdmin, and export the table structure it shows the following:

```
`unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL
```

Why the (11)? Doesn't `int` tell mySQL everything it needs to know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the number in parenthesis really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055564/what-does-the-number-in-parenthesis-really-mean)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the optional 'width' attribute, which can be used by applications to display the value.

To quote the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html):

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display
>   width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword
>   for the type. For example, [`INT(4)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) specifies an [`INT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) with a display
>   width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by
>   applications to display integer values having a width less than the
>   width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That
>   is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets.
>   Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does *not* constrain the range of values that can be
>   stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column
>   display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column
>   specified as [`SMALLINT(3)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) has the usual [`SMALLINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) range of `-32768` to
>   `32767`, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are
>   displayed in full using more than three digits.

Comment: In other words, the bracketed number is purely there as a hint on how to display the number. Internally, the int always occupies the same storage space, whether you display 1 digit or all of them.

Comment: till now i was thinking its to limit the range like `varchar(100)`...Learned new fact :)

Comment: If you use VARCHAR (n), it will make a difference. Not with numeric types tho.

Answer (score 5):

That sets the display width which is returned with the result set. It has no bearing on the storage size.