# How to optimize this mysql join on large table?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, query-optimization

I have a project where the admin needs to create multiple newsletters with some crawled posts from the web.

I insert the posts in `posts` table after crawling has completed and assign them a `feed_id` to identify the source. this is the structure of `posts` table (truncated):

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `identifier` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longtext,
  ...
  ...
  `is_unread` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every admin (user) has access to one or more "feeds". So in Newsletter creation page I want to show them a list of posts from the feeds they are allowed to see and also, I show a button to put the posts in specifict categories of that newsletter, if the user previously selected that post, I should show him that and let him remove it from the category. So I have some other tables too: `newsletters`, `categories`, `newsletter_post`, `category_post`. Here is their structures:

`newsletters`:

```
CREATE TABLE `newsletters` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`categories`:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`newsletter_post`:

```
CREATE TABLE `newsletter_post` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `newsletter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`category_post`:

```
CREATE TABLE `category_post` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So I'm using this query to find posts for the allowed feeds and check the status if a post is in a specific category of this specific newsletter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `posts`.`id`, `published`, `posts`.`title`, `posts`.`content`, `source_name`, `category_id`, `newsletter_id`, `link_href`, categories.title as category_title
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `category_post` ON `posts`.`id` = `category_post`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `category_post`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `newsletter_post` ON `posts`.`id` = `newsletter_post`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `newsletters` ON `newsletters`.`id` = `newsletter_post`.`newsletter_id`
WHERE `feed_id` IN (6, 7) ORDER BY `posts`.`published` DESC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

but the problem is this is horrible and not optimized. My `posts` table contains up to 50,000 rows each month, and each row with 3~10kbs of data in avg., so sometimes when I try to run the query (which is frequently run by the admin to make the newsletter, pagination etc) mysql shows this error: too much rows to join, etc. and most of the times its really slow.

and the reason I'm doing all this in one query is because I want the result to be in one json response so I can show them the user quickly without doing additional requests.

I wanna know if there is a better way to do this query or use indexes or something else.
Thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: please paste the explain plan

Comment: @SashiKant this is the explain plan: http://d.pr/i/UKgh (posts table contains ~2500 rows right now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

index your posts table on

( feed_id, published )

so the data is already optimized for your WHERE clause, and pre-sorted to help your ORDER BY.

Comment: Just normal indexes like the ones Sashi mentioned above for other tables?

Comment: yes, indexes from your tables should also be based on the criteria/order you are expecting to get results on a normal basis... IN ADDITION to those requiring joins to pk/fk of tables.  But even those to other tables could be multiple column indexes if you are joining on ex:  TableA.SomeKey = TableB.ForeignSomeKey AND TableB.OtherField='SomeStatus'... Your TableB would benefit from an index on ( ForeignSomeKey, OtherField ) for the join.

Comment: thanks, one more question, what If I need to sort based on something other than `published`? like source_name ? because the admin has the choose sorting type

Comment: +1, Correct. Indexing on WHERE/ORDER BY columns will improve performance.

Comment: @SallarKaboli, then have another index available by the criteria/order you will be using.  The engine SHOULD pick the index best suited for the request.

Answer (score 3):

For reading querys that have a lot of demand, InnoDB is very inefficient. I recommend you to use a NoSQL Database but if you don't want or the cost of change is too much... you can try this:

1) LIKE Sallar Kaboli told you, you have to index your tables in columns that use in JOIN querys. For example:

```
      CREATE INDEX index1 ON newsletter_post (post_id);
```

2) USE only important columns for JOINS.

I mean, you have to only use the columns that use in SELECT part of query.

I hope this'd be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it would be very helpful for your case. First, you have to analyze the cost of change and learning. A lot of people believe that MongoDB is the solution of all problems but not. But I think could be helpful for your particular case.

Answer (score 2):

To complete other answers, I suggest to change this types on `posts` table:

1) Change `feed_id` to `int(4)`. Really you have more than `int(4)` feeds?
2) Change `is_unread` to `bit` instead of `int(1)`. I should say that this may not improve your given query in the question but according to the field name, the correct type is `bit`.

Another more improvement to this answer is that never use default `int(11)` for numeric or id fields, assign types more specific. Using smaller size of types will improve your indexes also. I don't think you need more than `int(4)` for fields id.

For example indexing and querying `int(3)` column is more faster than `int(11)`.

Comment: Thanks Afshin, I've never used `bit` so I didn't know it existed :)

Comment: This answer contains some misinformation about the integer data type. The number within the parentheses doesn't affect the number of bytes used to store it. You should use the appropriate integer type, e.g. `INT`, `SMALLINT`,  `TINYINT` etc. if you want to reduce the number of bytes used to store the value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4055587/1220706

Answer (score 1):

Please create the following indexes indexes on ::

```
1) `post_id` in `category_post`
2) `post_id` in `newsletter_post`
```

Comment: I added the indexes and the query got much faster than before: 0.1 vs 0.9s. Do I need to add indexes to `feed_id` and `published` in `posts` because I use this columns in WHERE and ORDER BY?

Comment: @SallarKaboli: Look these were the columns which were letting the DB engine to scan all the rows, Their indexes were of much priority, Regarding the index on the columns you are mentioning, you can paste the updated explain plan, so that I can check whether it can again be optimized

Comment: Yes you need to add an index on feed_id too, then it will be much more optimized