# Is there any 'intn' datatype in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was working on a project recently and fiddling around with sql, when I accidentally forgot to put the () brackets in int(n), however it didn't result in an error and the table was created. This 'intn' datatype also behaves a lot different that int(n), int1/int2/int3/int4 all accept integers less than 128/32768/8388608/2147483648 which is 2^(8n-1), n being the number after int. On the other hand no matter what integer I give inside int(n) it always accepts up to 2147483647 while it should accept only n digits. Can someone pls explain the weird behavior of both these datatypes in layman's terms (I have just started learning SQL). Can you also tell me the correct syntax that I should use while using integer datatype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the number in parenthesis really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055564/what-does-the-number-in-parenthesis-really-mean)

Comment: Thanks, I got the bit about int(n), but can you also explain how 'intn' works as I had asked in the first part of the question

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? `intn` is not a valid type in MySQL.

Comment: I think Akina did answer the question, but anyway my SQL version is "8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These datatypes are aliases (see [Using Data Types from Other Database Engines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html)):

| datatype | is alias of |
| --- | --- |
| INT1 | TINYINT |
| INT2 | SMALLINT |
| INT3 | MEDIUMINT |
| INT4 | INT |
| INT8 | BIGINT |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c5545953ef496acf7893c28c198c3cb

Another variants (for example, `INT5`) will cause syntax error.